# Svelte Reactivity

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Trying to convert a simple tutorial that was using localStorage to instead use IndexedDB, but having trouble with reactivity. The list of movies don't update until i do a page refresh. Anyone who can point me in the right dirction? Thanks!

Below code updated with some changes suggested by Thomas Hennes in one of the answers, thanks! Still having problem with needing a manual page refresh though. Also added MovieList.svelte

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import MovieInput from "./MovieInput.svelte";
    import MovieList from "./MovieList.svelte";
    import Search from "./Search.svelte";
    import db from "./db.js";
    import Dexie from "dexie";

    //get a promise containing all movies in IndexedDB (if collection exists)
    let movies = db.movies.count(function (value) {
        return (movies = value > 0 ? db.movies.toArray() : []);
    });

    //add new item to IndexedDb
    const submitMovie = (movie) => {
        db.movies.put({ title: movie.title, rating: movie.rating });
    };
</script>

<div class="main">
    <h1>Movie Journal</h1>

    <MovieInput on:submitMovie={(event) => submitMovie(event.detail.movie)} />
    {#await movies}
        <div>Loading movies...</div>
    {:then movieArray}
        <MovieList {movieArray} />
    {:catch error}
        <div>Error loading movies: {error.message}</div>
    {/await}
</div>

<style>
    .main {
        width: 500px;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 1em;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #ff3e00;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 4em;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
</style>
```

Adding MovieList as well, might be there that I'm doing something wrong:

And MovieList.svelte

```
<script>
    export let movieArray;
</script>

{#each movieArray as movie}
    <div>
        <h3>{movie.title}</h3>
        <p>Your Rating: {movie.rating}</p>
    </div>
{/each}

<style>
    div {
        text-align: left;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Consider refactoring the statement `movies = db.movies.count ...` into a simpler `movies = loadMovies()` to avoid code repetition between your initial load and your refresh action after adding a movie.

Comment: I actually did that when I started implementing search functionality as well! Added the updated code for that at the end of my question. Feels a bit unneccessary to get the database all the time so thinking of using some temp array when searching, but for the time being it works atleast :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `movies` holds a promise that resolves to an array of movies, the Svelte way is to use an `{#await ...}` block:

```js
<script>
    import MovieInput from "./MovieInput.svelte";
    import MovieList from "./MovieList.svelte";
    import Search from "./Search.svelte";
    import db from "./db.js";
    import Dexie from "dexie";

    // not needed, the resulting data array will be created within the
    // {#await ...} block
    // let movieArray = [];

    //get a promise containing all movies in IndexedDB (if collection exists)
    let movies = db.movies.count(function (value) {
        return (movies = value > 0 ? db.movies.toArray() : []);
    });

    // not needed, use an {#await ...} block to handle resolution or error 
    // push items in promise to movieArray
    // movies
    //    .then((movies) => {
    //        movies.forEach(function (movie) {
    //            movieArray.push(movie);
    //        });
    //    })
    //    .catch((error) => {
    //        console.log(error);
    //    }).finally(() => {
    //        movieArray = movieArray;
    //    });

    //add new item to IndexedDb
    const submitMovie = (movie) => {
        db.movies.put({ title: movie.title, rating: movie.rating });
    };
</script>

<div class="main">
    <h1>Movie Journal</h1>

    <MovieInput on:submitMovie={(event) => submitMovie(event.detail.movie)} />
    {#await movies}
        <div>Loading movies...</div>
    {:then movieArray}
        <MovieList {movieArray} />
    {:catch error}
        <div>Error loading movies: {error.message}</div>
    {/await}
</div>

<style>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: Hi! And thanks, that does remove some code and looks nicer and I've verified it works like that, but the list still needs a manual page refresh to update on screen.

Comment: What do you mean by update? If you are changing the db's contents and expect the page to automatically refresh itself then it's not going to happen. Or do you mean that the list is empty on initial render and you need to manually refresh the page to see data?

Comment: Now I feel stupid for not seeing it :D I'm only getting the collection at page load, of course it won't update unless I refresh page. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my miss there Thomas, I added getting the collection again when submitting new items and now it works (at least visually) as I wanted.